# iterating through IEnumerable<string> causing serious performance issue

Tags: c#, performance

I am clue less about what has happend to performance of for loop when i tried to iterate through IEnumerable type.

Following is the code that cause serious performance issue

```
foreach (IEdge ed in edcol)
{
    IEnumerable<string> row = 
        from r in dtRow.AsEnumerable()
        where (((r.Field<string>("F1") == ed.Vertex1.Name) && 
                (r.Field<string>("F2") == ed.Vertex2.Name))
            || ((r.Field<string>("F1") == ed.Vertex2.Name) &&
                (r.Field<string>("F2") == ed.Vertex1.Name)))
        select r.Field<string>("EdgeId");
    int co = row.Count();
    //foreach (string s in row)
    //{

    //}
    x++;
}
```

The upper foreach(IEdge ed in edcol) has about 11000 iteration to complete.
It runs in fraction of seconds if i remove the line

```
int co = row.Count();
```

from the code.

The row.Count() have maximum value of 10 in all loops.

If i Uncomment the

```
//foreach (string s in row)
//{

//}
```

it goes for about 10 minutes to complete the execution of code.

Does IEnumerable type have such a serious performance issues.. ??

Comment: Without the `Count` the query won't be evaluated.

Comment: The performance issue is probably `dtRow.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: @mipe34 not *quite*; that doesn't actually do anything much; most things in LINQ use deferred execution

Comment: If dtRow.AsEnumerable() is performance issue then why code is running in fraction of seconds when remove row.count() line from code  ?

Comment: @Jon there is no code there that talks to a database. From the code shown, `dtRow` looks to be a `DataTable`. A `DataTable` doesn't load itself just because you look at it: either it has data, or it doesn't.

Comment: @mipe34 - The problem isn't `AsEnumerable` but that the query isn't evaluated until the enumerable is iterated.

Comment: dtRow is a datatable that has almost 100000 records

Comment: @RajeevKumar *there* we go; 100000 * 11000...

Comment: @MarcGravell: Right, I read too fast.

Comment: Okay, so now we know that filtering 100,000 rows 11,000 times is slow.  That's not terribly surprising. It's not clear what that actual *question* is...

Comment: but quesion is it runs actually very fast after removing row.Count() line, with                                         IEnumerable<string> row =  from r in dtRow.AsEnumerable()
                                    where (((r.Field<string>("F1") == ed.Vertex1.Name) && (r.Field<string>("F2") == ed.Vertex2.Name)) || ((r.Field<string>("F1") == ed.Vertex2.Name) && (r.Field<string>("F2") == ed.Vertex1.Name)))
                                        select r.Field<string>("EdgeId");                                                       still there .

Comment: @RajeevKumar: Yes, because then you're not doing any work. You're *building* a query, but never actually executing it. LINQ uses lazy evaluation, in general.

Comment: @JonSkeet I suppose it is how to make it quicker, which is refactoring the code rather than a question I guess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is for the implicit question of "how do I make this much faster"? Apologies if that's not *actually* what you were after, but...

You can go through the rows *once*, grouping by the names. (I haven't done the ordering like Marc has - I'm just looking up twice when querying :)

```
var lookup = dtRow.AsEnumerable()
                  .ToLookup(r => new { F1 = r.Field<string>("F1"),
                                       F2 = r.Field<string>("F2") });
```

Then:

```
foreach (IEdge ed in edcol)
{
    // Need to check both ways round...
    var first = new { F1 = ed.Vertex1.Name, F2 = ed.Vertex2.Name };
    var second = new { F1 = ed.Vertex2.Name, F2 = ed.Vertex1.Name };
    var firstResult = lookup[first];
    var secondResult = lookup[second];

    // Due to the way Lookup works, this is quick - much quicker than
    // calling query.Count()
    var count = firstResult.Count() + secondResult.Count();

    var query = firstResult.Concat(secondResult);

    foreach (var row in query)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes I worry about how similarly we tend to approach things. Very minor difference - to avoid the `Concat`, I enforced ascending tuples and used an element projection.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yeah... I don't know which would be faster, but I doubt that it makes much difference.

Comment: This execute the code with around 500000 records in datatable in 3 seconds !!! Thanks a lot

Comment: @RajeevKumar: Do you understand *why*?

Comment: @RajeevKumar: Well do you understand why the original code is slow... and why if you take out the `Count()` call (and the inner `foreach` loop) it's fast?

Comment: @JonSkeet : No i really dont know why this code runs so fast as compare to previous one which i am using

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23273/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-rajeev-kumar)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you have O(N*M) performance, which could be probematic if both N and M are large. I would be inclined to pre-compute some of the `DataTable` info. For example, we could try:

```
var lookup = dtRows.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(
        row => string.Compare(row.Field<string>("F1"),row.Field<string>("F2"))<0
           ? Tuple.Create(row.Field<string>("F1"), row.Field<string>("F2"))
           : Tuple.Create(row.Field<string>("F2"), row.Field<string>("F1")),
        row => row.Field<string>("EdgeId"));
```

then we can iterate that:

```
foreach(IEdge ed in edCol)
{
    var name1 = string.Compare(ed.Vertex1.Name,ed.Vertex2.Name) < 0
           ? ed.Vertex1.Name : ed.Vertex2.Name;
    var name2 = string.Compare(ed.Vertex1.Name,ed.Vertex2.Name) < 0
           ? ed.Vertex2.Name : ed.Vertex1.Name;

    var matches = lookup[Tuple.Create(name1,name2)];
    // ...
}
```

(note I enforced ascending alphabetical pairs in there, for convenience)

Comment: @JonSkeet er, yeah, probably